# how do I add a % to my SASS calculation?

Tags: css, sass

Im using SASS to convert width dimensions to % based on the element width and container width, my problem is however if I add % on to the end of my calculation I get an error, can anyone advise how I resolve this?

```
@mixin percentageWidth( $elementWidth, $containerWidth ){
  width: (($elementWidth/$containerWidth)*100) + %;
  *width: ((($elementWidth/$containerWidth)*100) - ((0.5/$containerWidth)*100)) + %;
}
```

Comment: You don't need all those parens. `a/b*c` instead of `((a/b)*c)`, and `a/b*c-d/e*f` instead of `(((a/b)*c)-((d/e)*f))`.

Comment: thanks, how could I update this mixin so I can use different properties like margin-right or width or padding?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions), you need to multiply the results by `100%` instead of trying to add `%` as though it were a string:

```
width: ($elementWidth/$containerWidth) * 100%;
*width: (($elementWidth/$containerWidth) - (0.5/$containerWidth)) * 100%;
```